# QGIS 2.8 Convert a vector to a raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, qgis-2.8

When I change a vector layer to raster using `raster button->converse->Vector rasterization` in QGIS2.8. I get only a black picture.
Why is that so and how can I convert a vector layer to a raster layer.

Comment: It sounds like at some point you're off your spatial reference which means the raster doesn't line-up with your vector (or the other way around). Are you trying to rasterize into an existing raster or create a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Rasterization depends of the field that you select. For example, in the following case I selected (in vector layer **point_2**) the 'field' field whose values are all 0. The result, **point_2_raster.tif**, is the same that you are obtaining (a black picture):

[image]

However, if the 'id' field is selected, whose values are between 1 and 5, the result (**point_raster.tif**) is totally different:

[image]

It could be your problem.